# How does Jackson marshalling work with Kotlin data class?

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I have a simple data class being returned from a REST endpoint.

```
data class SummarizedReturn(
    val NET_CASH_FLOW: BigDecimal,
    val ROI_PERCENTAGE: BigDecimal
)
```

When it is returned, the object looks like this:

```
{
    summarizedReturn: {
        net_CASH_FLOW: -194703.12028723184,
        roi_PERCENTAGE: -35,
    }
}
```

This is not what I need. I need all letters to be capitalized. So I added the `JsonProperty` annotation

```
data class SummarizedReturn(
    @JsonProperty("NET_CASH_FLOW")
    val NET_CASH_FLOW: BigDecimal,
    @JsonProperty("ROI_PERCENTAGE")
    val ROI_PERCENTAGE: BigDecimal,
)
```

This did not change anything. I still get the result the same as above.

I then changed the property names and kept the annotation

```
data class SummarizedReturn(
    @JsonProperty("NET_CASH_FLOW")
    val netCashFlow: BigDecimal,
    @JsonProperty("ROI_PERCENTAGE")
    val roiPercentage: BigDecimal,
)
```

and that returned what I wanted.

```
{
    summarizedReturn: {
        NET_CASH_FLOW: -194703.12028723184,
        ROI_PERCENTAGE: -35,
    }
}
```

Why did the annotation not work on the initial version of the class? How can I keep my property names all capitalized and have the Jackson value to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with interoperability of Java annotations in Kotlin code. You can register Jackson's Kotlin module to get rid of this problems:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper

fun main() {
    val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper() // <= shortcut to ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
    println(mapper.writeValueAsString(SummarizedReturn(
            BigDecimal("-194703.12028723184"),
            BigDecimal("-35"))))
}
```

**Output:**

> {"NET_CASH_FLOW":-194703.12028723184,"ROI_PERCENTAGE":-35}

This will also require you to add `com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin` to your dependencies.

**PS:** Alternatively you can solve it by using slightly different target:
`@JsonPropery` => `@get:JsonPropery` (or `field:@JsonPropery` in case this data class will also be used for deserialization)

Comment: I pulled in the `kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper` and wrote it out as a string and got the same result. Any ideas?